# Search file, show matches and first line

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, grep

I've got a comma separated textfile, which contains the column headers in the first line:

```
column1;column2;colum3
foo;123;345
bar;345;23
baz;089;09
```

Now I want a **short** command that outputs the first line and the matching line(s). Is there a shorter way than:

```
head -n 1 file ; cat file | grep bar
```

Comment: Maybe I should add: I like to have the search string at the end of the line, so I can quickly change the search term when doing multiple searches in a row. (arrow-up, ctrl+W, enter new search string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
cat file | awk 'NR<2;$0~v' v=baz
column1;column2;colum3
baz;089;09
```

Usually `cat file | ...` is useless but in this case it keeps the file argument out of the way and allows the variable `v` to be amended quickly.

Another solution:

```
cat file | sed -n '1p;/foo/p' 
column1;column2;colum3
foo;123;345
```

Comment: You could also write: `awk -v v=baz 'NR<2;$0~v' file` without cat.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about the possibility to use a variable with awk!

Comment: +1 for the first time I saw `awk` code including `$0~` for a reason.

Comment: To get rid of the problem noted by Zsolt Botykai, you should probably use `cat file | awk 'NR<2||$0~v' v=baz`, instead. This way you ensure the first line is printed only once, even if it matched `baz`.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the job:

```
sed -n '1p;2,${/bar/p}' file
```

where:

- `1p` will print the first line
- `2,$` will match from second line to the last line
- `/bar/p` will print those lines that match `bar`

Note that this won't print the header line twice if there's a match in the columns names.

Comment: just one more way : `sed -e '1{p;d;};/bar/!d' file`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [grouping commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping), then pipe to `column` command for pretty-printing

```
$ { head -1; grep bar; } <input.txt | column -ts';'
column1  column2  colum3
bar      345      23
```

Answer (score 3):

What if the first row contains `bar` too? Then it's printed two times with your version. `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print } NR > 1 && $0 ~ "bar" { print }' FILE
```

If you want the search sting as the almost last item on the line:

```
awk 'ARGIND > 1 { exit } NR == 1 { print } NR > 1 && $0 ~ ARGV[2] { print }' FILE YOURSEARCHSTRING 2>/dev/null
```

`sed` solution:

```
sed -n '1p;1d;/bar/p' FILE
```

The advantage for both of them, that it's a single process.

Comment: true, didn't think of that. But honestly I don't care since I'm doing the search manually for a quick lookup and am not using the output afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

`head -n 1 file && grep bar file` Maybe there is even a shorter version but will get a bit complicated.

EDIT: as per bobah 's comment I have added && between the commands to have only a single error for missing file

Comment: I like complicated. Also if the search string is at the end of the line, its faster to do multiple searches (ARROW-UP,CTRL+W, enter new string)

Comment: +1, i would separate cmds with "&&", not ";" to have only one error message printed for missing file

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest command yet:

```
awk 'NR==1||/bar/' file
```

Comment: But it doesn't match all of the OPs requirements (see comment).